# Nodejs VM. Set memory limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, virtual-machine

I'm working now with nodejs virtual machine:

http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html

I'm interesting, is it possible to set memory limit to script and maybe limit to CPU?

Comment: did you achieved any how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this at the V8 VM level without affecting the rest of your code that runs in the same process. If you are wanting to incorporate these kinds of restrictions, you should be executing the code in a separate process that is properly contained (using the appropriate mechanisms provided by the OS). Linux has [cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups), FreeBSD has [jails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail), and Solaris has [zones/containers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_Containers).

Answer (score 0):

You can use isolated-vm npm and pass memoryLimit option parameter.